Share privileges across several postgresql servers
I have several Postgresql servers on a local network, and I need them to have the same users/roles, privileges, etc.
To achieve part of this, we can use LDAP to handle the user verification, pg-ldap-sync to sync all the users with PG so we don't need to create the user manually.
What remains is how can a user have the same privileges on all the servers?
I can't get any answer to this. This also implies in same way to share them, if a server changes a privilege the other servers should update it.
Maybe there is a middle point, which could be Postgres Replication, CITUS uses it, could be useful but also can't found how to handle the privileges on servers like this.
If you are asking "Do you want to have also the same data in all servers for high availability?"
My answer is yes, is related but maybe too off topic, after all, the missing piece is shared privileges.
